# Can tab view be used in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I am trying to achieve UI shown as below.

Header which can be included in xml,same goes to search text view as it is a reusable view.
 **Problem I am facing is to make tab view , each having list item and as usual tabs should be slidable**. 
 I am planning to use base class which extends `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

 At the end there is a footer also. Below is the UI which I am trying to achieve. Any help is really appreciable.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). This will handle the sliding.

For the tabs, you can use the good ol' [`TabWidget`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) or the new [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) from the Design Support library